# Where should I populate a control based on a selected value from master page

Tags: asp.net, events, master-pages

I have the following situation:

- Master page contains a tree control
- Page use the previous master page
- Control populates its items based on the selected node in the tree (which is in the master page)

The question is:
Where should I populate a control based on a selected value from master page?

The problem is that the `Load` event of the master page is fired after the `Load` event of the page, so I couldn't handle the selected node from the master page in the `Load` event of the page.

I tried also to use the `PreRender` event of the page, but the control is not populated true.

Any help!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Get the value which was set in the master page and use it in the page to populate a control

Comment: try using delegate to chain the events in the order you need them to execute or hook to the SelectedIndexChange event of the tree control and do the work in there

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I'm guessing you are building/binding the list in the masterpage's load event and then reading the selected index/value in the child pages load event.

Instead try building/binding in the masterpage init event, then reading it in the pages load event should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the NavigateUrl to the page which should be loaded and pass the selected node value as query strings.

In the example below, I'd subscribed to OnTreeNodeDataBound event on the TreeView.
In the event handler, I'd customized the NavigateUrl by adding query string (in this case selected node value).

ex:

TreeView Markup in Master page:

```
<asp:TreeView ID='TreeView1' runat='server' DataSourceID='SiteMapDataSource1' OnTreeNodeDataBound='HandleOnTreeViewTreeNodeDataBound'>        
</asp:TreeView>
```

code-behind:

```
public void HandleOnTreeViewTreeNodeDataBound(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
        String newUrl = String.Format("{0}?nodeValue={1}", e.Node.NavigateUrl, e.Node.Value);
        e.Node.NavigateUrl = newUrl;
}
```